# Pyplot is showing different colors for the same value?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, signal-processing

Given that, I have two, almost identical, arrays and then I plot them as gray images but the output shows the **value 12 as gray from one array** and **white from the other**, what am I missing?

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# In[2]:

ori = [[ 12.,  11.,  12.],
 [ 12.,  12.,  12.],
 [ 13.,  12.,  11.]]

qtz = [[ 13.,  12.,  12.],
 [ 12.,  12.,  13.],
 [ 12.,  13.,  12.]]


# In[3]:

plt.imshow(ori, interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()

print('#############')

plt.imshow(qtz, interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

[image: original]
[image: quantized]

Comment: It is because the colormap will be scaled according to the lowest and highest values of arrays.

Comment: Thank you @J.P.Petersen can I force it to assume other values?

Comment: I didn't understand why the `downvote` though.

Comment: Don't try to understand down-votes, there are just some bad actors floating around.

Comment: As @tacaswell said, you shouldn't put too much into a downvote. And sometimes downvotes attract more downvotes, so there can be a kind of avalanche effect. You can read much about this sort of things on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said [J. P. Petersen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681870/j-p-petersen) the problem is that the colormap automatically chooses the color scale.

You can fix it with `vmin` and `vmax`:

```
plt.imshow(ori, interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.binary, vmin=11, vmax=13)

plt.imshow(qtz, interpolation='nearest',cmap=plt.cm.binary, vmin=11, vmax=13)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow) when I also found the answer.